# Функции, вызываемые из DLL

Tags: delphi, dll

Какая разница между функциями DLL и внутренними функциями, кроме того что dll можно передавать (качать, давать и т.п.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL - (если своими словами) универсальное хранилище функций.

*Примеры использования:*

- Вы написали DLL на Delphi. Ваш друг
     может ее использовать при написании
     программ на С++;
- Плагины для    программы;

Answer (score 3):

Разница кардинальная.

DLL - это файл, который можно определенным образом подключить к программе *.EXE и из программы вызывать функции из библиотеки и использовать переменные из библиотеки.
При этом несколько программ могут использовать одну DLL. Это позволяет вынести часто используемые функции в DLL и сэкономить память. Также если несколько программ используют одну библиотеку, то исправив ошибку в какой-нибудь функции, то исправление распространится на все программы. Обратная сторона - т.н. "DLL Hell", когда разные версии программ используют разные версии одних библиотек и в результате получаются конфликты.
Так же с помощью DLL очень удобно наращивать функционал программы. Т.к. можно базовую функциональность реализовать в EXE, а через DLL реализовывать плагины (например, WinAMP, Foobar).
К тому же библиотека DLL доступа в принципе всем программам, которые знают к ней путь. Т.е. если она есть в системе, то никто не мешает вызвать эту библиотеку из "левого" приложения. Даже если разработчик этой библиотеки этого не хотел :-)
PS: DLL тоже могут вызывать ф-ции из DLL

А функция - это языковая конструкция. Никто не мешает дать другу Вашу функцию в виде исходного кода (*.PAS-файл), чтобы он включил ее в свою программу. Как вариант - можно сделать статически компонованную библиотеку. Это по сути объектный файл (т.е. откомпилированный исходник). Но придется еще файл описания делать. Тут уже не подскажу, но в справке Delphi это все есть :-) Копать в сторону Unit'ов (модулей)

Comment: А файл описания в любом случае надо делать =) Ну, если давать откомпилированный так или иначе код =3

Answer (score 1):

К **.dll** написанной на *Delphi* можно обращаться из программ разработанных на других языках, т.к. поскольку существует соглашение о вызове подпрограмм из **.dll**, которое принято в *C++* и называют стандартным. Кроме того фрагменты кода могут вызываться из .**dll** несколькими приложениями одновременно, при этом они не находятся постоянно в памяти, а подгружаются по мере вызова, что уменьшает место занимаемое программами и расход ОЗУ.
И вообще, функции и процедуры - состаные элементы .dll, на мой взгляд - это главное отличие.

Answer (score 1):

Могу добавить, что в виде аргументов фикций библиотек желательно использовать резко ограниченный набор типов, так как необходимо обеспечить бинарную совместимость вызова. Это типы: `longint, real, pchar, pointer`, но это не накладывает ни каких ограничений по большому счету. Так можно передать указатель на статический метод и класс, реализующий метод, в качестве параметров функции dll.

Основные сложности заключаются в организации памяти и самого вызова. Так *dephi*/*free pascal*/*gnu pascal* придерживаются того, что ко всем функциям применяться параметр `fastcall`, где в регистрах первым передается указатель на объект и указатели на значения параметров, если их не более двух. Это соглашение не стандартизовано, поэтому надо применять `stdcall` (указывается за заголовком метода в интересной области и области реализации), который и является стандартом dll. Это обязывает транслятор создавать код так, что освобождением памяти будет заниматься вызванная подпрограмма. Соглашение по вызову `сcall` наоборот, обязывает следить за памятью вызывавшую подпрограмму.

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб внести полную ясность добавлю что это все не относится к .dll файлам откопилированным в среде .Net т.к. .dll сделанные не в .Net например Delph или С++ это  **универсальное хранилище функций** или "unmananged code" по терминалогии .Net ,а .dll сделанные в .Net. это  **универсальное хранилище классов** т.е. соответственно "mananged code" самая близкая аналогия которую я знаю это .Bpl файлы Borlanda.